# Directories and Sub-directories are not showing on open editors of vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, subdirectory, vscode-tasks

I have issues in my visual Studio code that the subfolders are not able to displaying. I just have to open every single file in my project. Even open editors is not showing folder option.

Actually on visual studio code I just have to open a every single file even which are present in sub-folders.

Comment: 1) some screenshots demonstrating what you're seeing would be quite helpful here. 2) are you using any sort of remote connection (Ex. SSH, WSL, FTP)?